# Unable to disable checkbox

Tags: php

My problem here is that my checkbox will only be disabled when all the checkboxs status is 0. But here, i only want the selected checkbox be disabled, but when the status of checkboxs is not all set to 0, it will not be disabled.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM box WHERE status = 1";
    $result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $num_rows = @mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $disable = '';
    if (!$num_rows) {
        $disable = 'disabled="disabled"';
    }    
?>

<form method = "post" action = "">    
    <input type='checkbox' name="boxs[]" id="1.1" value ="1.1" <?php echo $disable ?>/>
    <label for="1.1" class="background1"></label> <br/>
    <input type='checkbox' name="boxs[]" id="1.2" value ="1.2"<?php echo $disable ?>/>
    <label for="1.2" class="background2"></label> 
    <br/>
    <input type='checkbox' name="boxs[]" id="1.3" value ="1.3"<?php echo $disable ?>/>
    <label for="1.3" class="background2"></label> 
    <input type="submit" name="Next" id="Next" value="next" />
</form>
<?php    
    if(isset($_POST['Next'])) {   
        foreach($_POST['boxs'] as $f) {
            $sql = "UPDATE box SET status = '0' WHERE boxid = '$f'";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

            $result = "INSERT INTO booked(username, boxid) VALUES('$username', '$f')";
            mysqli_query($con,$result) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        }       
    }
?>
```

So, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: i checked your code. but can't find any problem.

Comment: then, do you have any idea to disable the checkbox?

Comment: i checked with  your code. when zero pases, all  check boxes will  disabled. when other numbers excpet zero passes, the checkbox will  enabled. i  am not find out  any  error.

Comment: same with me.I also faced this situation

Comment: please tell me what the problem is..

Comment: The checkbox will not disabled when only one checkbox status is 0. It will only be disable if all the three checkbox status is set to 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118975/discussion-between-jees-k-denny-and-june).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $username = $_SESSION['username'];?>
<form method = "post" action = "">
<?php
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM box WHERE boxid=1.1 AND status = 1";
  $result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $num_rows = @mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $disable = '';
  if (!$num_rows){
    $disable = 'disabled="disabled"';
  }
?>

<input type='checkbox' name="boxs[]" id="1.1" value ="1.1" <?php echo $disable ?>/>
<label for="1.1" class="background1"></label> <br/>
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM box WHERE boxid=1.2 AND status = 1";
  $result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $num_rows = @mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $disable = '';
  if (!$num_rows){
   $disable = 'disabled="disabled"';
  }
?>

<input type='checkbox' name="boxs[]" id="1.2" value ="1.2"<?php echo $disable ?>/>
<label for="1.2" class="background2"></label> 
<br/>
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM box WHERE boxid=1.3 AND status = 1";
  $result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $num_rows = @mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $disable = '';
  if (!$num_rows){
    $disable = 'disabled="disabled"';
  }
?>

<input type='checkbox' name="boxs[]" id="1.3" value ="1.3"<?php echo $disable ?>/>
<label for="1.3" class="background2"></label> 
<input type="submit" name="Next" id="Next" value="next" />
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Next']))
{   
foreach($_POST['boxs'] as $f){
$sql = "UPDATE box SET status = '0' WHERE boxid = '$f'";
mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$result = "INSERT INTO booked(username, boxid) VALUES('$username', '$f')";
mysqli_query($con,$result) or die(mysqli_error($con));
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the your exact requirement but; Your solutions may be

```
<?php $username = $_SESSION['username']; ?>
<form method = "post" action = "">
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM box";
$result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
$i=1;
while ($raw = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ($raw['status'] == 1) {
        $disable = 'disabled="disabled"';
    } else {
        $disable = '';
    }
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='boxs[]' id='" . $raw['boxid'] . "' value ='" . $raw['boxid'] . "' $disable/>";
    echo " <label for='" . $raw['boxid'] . "'  class='background$i'></label> <br/>";
 $i++;
}
?>
</form>
```

Comment: my checkbox has label, so each has different class

Comment: See the revised answer.

Comment: i want to arrange my checkbox in 3 column.How should i do it? the column need to look like tis:1.1 2.1 3.1